# How To add font awesome in magento 2

Tags: third-party-module

I am Facing An Isue While Uding Font Awesome 5 In magento 2 the icon does not come can anybody show me the exact and step by step guide of doing that.

Comment: You can add any script through the backend by going to `Content -> Design -> Configuration` editing your design and add the script in `Other Settings -> HTML Head -> Scripts and Stylesheets` (2.3.1)

Answer (score 7):

Ok i just google it and find a solution that works for me!!!

-> Under \Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

-> Put font awesome cdn url

-> Just Flush The Content

-> Know copy icon code from here https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery and use it

you need to have the param `src_type="url"` if you use an external URL eg:

```
<css src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" src_type="url"/>
```

Comment: you need to have the param ` src_type="url"` eg: ```<css src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" src_type="url"/>```